# Why internationalization is not working on NextJS 13 using a [locale] sub-folder on app/

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, internationalization, next.js13

## How to get i18n working on Next 13 ?

I have created a nested `[locale]/` folder in `app/` but it just gives a 404

See my **next.config.js**

```
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
  },
  i18n: {
    defaultLocale: 'fr,
    locales: ['fr', 'en'],
    localeDetection: true
  }
}
```

Did you find a way to support i18n with React Server components ?

**EDIT:**

On the [beta.nextjs](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/app-directory-roadmap#not-planned-features) doc it says :

> We are currently not planning to include the following features in app:
> Internationalization (i18n)

I have as well found an [open issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/41980) about it, which does not provide any workaround yet.

Comment: From [this](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/42174) and [this](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/30987) issue, It looks like it would be best to keep using the locale features within the `pages/` for now until the docs come out for something more comprehensive.

Comment: https://locize.com/blog/next-13-app-dir-i18n/

Answer (score 7):

[EDIT] There's a guide in [Next.js documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/internationalization) now.

[Middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware) is a solution to i18n in Next.js 13. Until there is an officially recommended way.

1. To use middleware in Next.js 13 with `/app` directory, you must create the `/page` directory (even if all your pages are going to be in `/app` directory) and a `.keep` file inside of it. [Github issue about it](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/41995#issuecomment-1295874078)
2. Create a dynamic route `[locale]` in the `app` directory and put all other routes there.
3. Set middleware so it redirects all traffic from routes without a `locale` param to ones that have it (f.e. based on `Accept-language` header or location of the client).
4. Get the value of the `locale` on a page from [params](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/data-fetching/fetching#parallel-data-fetching).

A minimal `middleware.ts` content inspired by [Eric Howey's article](https://www.erichowey.dev/writing/advanced-internationalization-with-nextjs-and-middleware/):

```js
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import type { NextRequest } from "next/server";

// Regex to check whether something has an extension, e.g. .jpg
const PUBLIC_FILE = /\.(.*)$/;

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const { nextUrl, headers } = request;
  // Cloned url to work with
  const url = nextUrl.clone();
  // Client language, defaults to en
  const language =
    headers
      .get("accept-language")
      ?.split(",")?.[0]
      .split("-")?.[0]
      .toLowerCase() || "en";

  try {
    // Early return if it is a public file such as an image or an api call
    if (PUBLIC_FILE.test(nextUrl.pathname) || nextUrl.pathname.includes("/api")) {
      return undefined;
    }

    // Proceed without redirection if on a localized path
    if (
      nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/en") ||
      nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/de") ||
      nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/fr")
    ) {
      return undefined;
    }

    if (language === "fr") {
      url.pathname = `/fr${nextUrl.pathname}`;
      return NextResponse.redirect(url);
    }

    if (language === "de") {
      url.pathname = `/de${nextUrl.pathname}`;
      return NextResponse.redirect(url);
    }

    if (!["de", "fr"].includes(language)) {
      url.pathname = `/en${nextUrl.pathname}`;
      return NextResponse.redirect(url);
    }

    return undefined;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice but how do you get the locale inside a server component or client component?

Comment: @GokhanKurt I've updated the answer to address your question.

Answer (score 0):

Even though i18n is no longer directly supported by Next.js in combination with the new app directory, there is still a way to solve this...

With the help of a middleware and with the use of i18next, react-i18next and i18next-resources-to-backend this is solvable.

It works on server side and on client side.

There's a little [example](https://github.com/i18next/next-13-app-dir-i18next-example) showing how this could work directly by using [i18next](https://www.i18next.com/) and [react-i18next](https://react.i18next.com/) on server side and on client side.

...and [here](https://locize.com/blog/next-13-app-dir-i18n/) the corresponding blog post.

A snipped on how this could look like:

server side:

```
import Link from 'next/link'
import { useTranslation } from '../i18n'
import { Footer } from './components/Footer'

export default async function Page({ params: { lng } }) {
  const { t } = await useTranslation(lng)
  return (
    <>
      <h1>{t('title')}</h1>
      <Link href={`/${lng}/second-page`}>
        {t('to-second-page')}
      </Link>
      <br />
      <Link href={`/${lng}/client-page`}>
        {t('to-client-page')}
      </Link>
      <Footer lng={lng}/>
    </>
  )
}
```

client side:

```
'use client'

import Link from 'next/link'
import { useTranslation } from '../../i18n/client'
import { Footer } from '../components/Footer/client'
import { useState } from 'react'

export default function Page({ params: { lng } }) {
  const { t } = useTranslation(lng, 'client-page')
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)
  return (
    <>
      <h1>{t('title')}</h1>
      <p>{t('counter', { count: counter })}</p>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => setCounter(Math.max(0, counter - 1))}>-</button>
        <button onClick={() => setCounter(Math.min(10, counter + 1))}>+</button>
      </div>
      <Link href={`/${lng}`}>
        <button type="button">
          {t('back-to-home')}
        </button>
      </Link>
      <Footer lng={lng} />
    </>
  )
}
```